# match multiple values with one expected values, always try to match only first value and fails

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor

I am using bellow mentioned code to compare multiple values with one expected values and if the text matches with anyone of them my test should pass :

```
Promise.all([Summ,Desc,Comment]).then(function(values){
    console.log("values = " +values);
    expect(values[0]||values[1]||values[2]).toMatch('searchtxt');
});
```

But with this code it always try to match first (values[0]), if this does not match then my test will fail.

How can I change it so that protractor looks for all 3 values and then if anyone of them matches my test should pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if anyone of them matches my test should pass

In this case, you don't need anything special, just *concatenate* the values:

```
expect(values[0] + values[1] + values[2]).toMatch('searchtxt');
```

Please also see the follow-up to your problem here:

- [One of strings in array to match an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37926523/771848)

Comment: @soniasharma btw, I've created a follow-up if you are interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926523/one-of-strings-in-array-to-match.

Comment: Yes,  Sure Thanks @alecxe .

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
expect(values[0] == searchtxt || values[1] == searchtxt || values[2] == searchtxt).toEqual(true);
```